# How to make download popup work in chrome when download data from api?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I Successfully download data from the API to excel but there's no download confirmation in chrome. It's just save it in the vendor problem. I want to make shown in Downloads of chrome

```
public function download()
    {
        $host ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        $process = curl_init($host); 

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);


        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $return = curl_exec($process);
        curl_close($process);




        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Id');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Name');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Skills');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Address');   
         $rows = 2;

         $results=json_decode($return);



        foreach ($results as $val){
            $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rows, $val->id);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rows, $val->userId);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $rows, $val->title);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $rows, $val->body);
            $rows++;
        } 


        $writer=new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('json.xlsx');



    }
```

Comment: its fixed... i just need to add echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=json.xlsx'/>";

Answer (score 0):

> Its not done by PHP Code your need is  Browser functionality 
>   check this link to make Chrome to show downloads [How to make chrome downloads to display](https://www.howtogeek.com/231002/how-to-change-the-chrome-download-folder-location/)